# How do I log into an iSCSI target using Virtual Disk Service (VDS) on Windows Server 2003 and higher?

Tags: c++, windows

Given the ip address and an iSCSI Qualified Name (iqn) of an iSCSI target as an input I need to write C++ or C# code that uses VDS (documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb986750(v=vs.85).aspx) to log into this iSCSI target.

I think that I could use the function IVdsIscsiInitiatorAdapter::LoginToTarget documented at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381779(v=vs.85).aspx. How do I create the target object and the target portal object so that I can pass their ids to this method as arguments?

I believe that I must have a hardware provider installed to be able to connect to iSCSI target.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a target API then you should look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh830439(v=vs.85).aspx

Be prepared to deal with WMI and it's a pain... Few samples in PowerShell (it would be
easy to translate to C++ or C# as it's WMI basically in any case):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278022.aspx

For initiator side (client) you'd look here (continued with the next post)

Answer (score 0):

(continued)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826099.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/san/archive/2012/07/31/managing-iscsi-initiator-connections-with-windows-powershell-on-windows-server-2012.aspx

And general one (continued with the next post)

Comment: This is all interesting information but my question was how to use Virtual Disk Service (VDS) to connect to an iSCSI target since I needed code that would work on Windosw Server 2003 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

(continued)

http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2012/06/08/iscsi-target-cmdlet-reference.aspx

Other Windows iSCSI targets have similar things. DataCore is scriptable with PowerShell and StarWind is coming with StarWindX OCX component you can call with PowerShell, C++, C# and VB.